# JQuery CSS color text except whitespace

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to apply a background color to all text except whitespace on Github and I'm unable to get that effect.

My CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/s7pkd5kz/1/

```
td {
    white-space: pre;
}

td.blob-code {
    background: black; 
    float: left; 
    color: black;
    padding: 0;
}

td.blob-code span {
    color: black;
}
```

Ideally: http://jsfiddle.net/osxfxcr4/1/

**I added a whitespace span around the whitespace in this example**

```
td {
    white-space: pre;
}

.whitespace {
    background: white;
    float: left;
}

td.blob-code {
    background: black; 
    float: left; 
    color: black;
    padding: 0;
}

td.blob-code span {
    color: black;
}
```

I'm using jQuery.css to style all the code so I can also use other jQuery methods to wrap the whitespace.

Comment: probably need to use script to wrap all spaces in a span with class

Comment: @charlietfl how do I do that?

Comment: by parsing the html and replacing spaces with spaces in spans